# How to get I certain data from json?

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to get certain data from twitter after doing a request.

```
import requests
import json 

username = input("Twitter Lookup: ")
url =  "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=" + username
page = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization":"my auth here"})

account = (page.json())

print(account['id'])
```

After I do this, it gives me the error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

The data shown when I print(account):

```
Twitter Lookup: random=
[{'id': 172831776, 'id_str': '172831776', 'name': 'Random', 'screen_name': 'random', 'location': '', 'description': 'Learn something new today.'}] and so on
```

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Apparently `account` is a `list` and not a `dict` as you assume in your code.

Comment: Could you show what the JSON looks like? Although, I think your problem should be solved if you use `print(account[0]['id'])`

Comment: Do `print(account)` and you'll see

Comment: Please update your question with a small sample of the data in the `account` variable.

Comment: I have updated with some of the json data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select the data like this.

`account` is a list of dictionaries, so you have to first select the dictionary and then get the `id`

```
account = [{'id': 172831776, 'id_str': '172831776', 'name': 'Random', 'screen_name': 'random', 'location': '', 'description': 'Learn something new today.'}] 

print(account[0]['id'])
print(account[0]['description'])
```

```
172831776
Learn something new today.
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Can you show what an example would look like if I wanted to get multiple of the data values?

Comment: You can just get them like you do in a dictionary. ```account[0][key]``` will give you the corresponding value. You can see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

A Json Array is also a valid json object in python.

Your account object could look something like this:

```
[
  {
   "id": "<some_id>",
  },
  {
   "id": "<some_id>",
  }
]
```

In which case you should try to access:

```
account[0]['id']
```

or whatever other index you are looking for